# Bootstrap popover placement incorrect

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover

I'm using Bootstrap 2.3.2. I grabbed some code off of the bootstrap website to make sure the code was correct, but I still can't get the position to change.

Here is a fiddle to show what's wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/4wJTR/

Could the JavaScript be incorrect?

```
$(function () {
    $('body').popover({
        selector: '[data-toggle="popover"]'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was the javascript. This fixed it:

```
$("a[data-toggle=popover]")
    .popover({ //Initializes popover and pass options
      animation: true,
      trigger: 'manual'
      })
    .click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).popover('toggle');
      e.stopPropagation();
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/46SY3/